# Cloudinary image browser disappeared with 0.3.22

Tags: keystonejs

I have just upgraded my Keystone version. The ability to browse cloudinary images seems to have disappeared. I can upload new ones fine, but can't access existing images from the UI. Is there a way to bring this back?

Comment: Is this the ability to browse images in the Admin UI, or see them as a function of a Mongo model? What exactly did you lose?

Comment: to browse in the admin UI

Comment: Same problem here